# Permitir login por email, CPF ou CNPJ Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, login, woocommerce

Preciso fazer um filtro onde é permitido fazer o login com o CPF ou CNPJ além dos já permitidos pelo Woocommerce, que é o email ou usuário, na página Minha Conta.
Resumindo, preciso que seja possível logar com email, usuário, cpf ou cnpj

Li que o filtro que pode fazer isso é o `add_filter( 'authenticate', 'my_custom_authenticate', 10, 3 );`
mas não sei como fazer.

Estou usando o plugin [WooCommerce Extra Checkout Fields for Brazil](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-extra-checkout-fields-for-brazil/) para adicionar os campos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei exatamente como esse plugin guarda os dados, mas o código pra fazer o login funcionar com eles vai ser algo assim.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'ptstackoverflow_auth_com_cpf_ou_cpnj', 99, 3 );

function ptstackoverflow_auth_com_cpf_ou_cpnj( $user, $username, $password ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Se o primeiro parametro não é null, o usuário já está autenticado
    if ( $user ) {
        return $user;
    }

     // Passo 1: procurar no banco um usuário que tenha aquele CPF ou CNPJ 
     // ( que está na variável $username ).
     // exemplo, supondo que as meta_keys sejam "cpf" e "cnpj":
     $user_row = $wpdb->get_results( 
        $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta 
                         WHERE ( meta_key = 'cpf' AND meta_value = '%s') 
                         OR ( meta_key = 'cnpj' AND meta_value = '%s' )",
                        $username, $username ) );

    // Passo 2: Se encontrou, pega o objeto desse usuário,
    // confere a senha
     if ( ! empty( $user_row ) ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_row[0]->ID );
        // Passo 3: Se a senha confere você retorna o objeto do usuário (WP_User)
        if ( wp_check_password( $password, $user->user_pass, $user_row[0]->ID ) ) {
            return $user;
        }       
     }

     /** 
     * Se não encontrou ou se a senha não confere, retorne um objeto WP_Error 
     * com a mensagem que deve aparecer 
     */
    return new WP_Error( '', 'mensagem de erro', $username );
}
```

**Isso é apenas um exemplo**, precisa ser modificado para funcionar no seu caso.

Answer (score 1):

Obrigada pela ajuda! Consegui fazer a autenticação, mas apenas para um tipo (CPF ou CNPJ), gostaria de verificar para os dois. Creio que é na hora de fazer o $wpdb-prepare, mas de acordo com minhas pesquisas, não consigo fazer dois SELECT's ao mesmo tempo.
Segue como está meu código verificando apenas por CPF:

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'login_cpf_cnpj', 10, 3);
function login_cpf_cnpj($user, $username, $password){
   if ($username == '' || $password == '') return;

   global $wpdb;
   if ($user) {
     return $user;
   }
    $user_row = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}usermeta 
                     WHERE ( meta_key = 'billing_cpf' AND meta_value = '%s') 
                     OR ( meta_key = 'billing_cnpj' AND meta_value = '%s' )",
        $username, $username ) );

   if (!empty($user_row)) {
     $user = get_user_by('ID', $user_row[0]->user_id);
     if ($user && wp_check_password($password, $user->user_pass, $user_row[0]->user_id)) {
        return $user;
     } else { ?>
          <script>
              alert('Senha Inválida!');
              window.location = "<?php get_permalink(); ?>";
          </script>
        <?php
     }
  }
  return $user;
}
```

UPDATE: conforme resposta do Ricardo, alterei o meu código para buscar 2 campos.

Comment: atualizei a minha resposta com o código buscando em 2 campos

Comment: Muito Obrigada Ricardo! Deu certinho!

Comment: Perfeito! Esse tópico me ajudou bastante. Obrigado à todos. Eu também tava tentando criar a mesma funcionalidade com login e cadastro por Ajax no meu site, e acabei adaptando o meu código com a consulta ao banco de dados usando a função proposta aqui. Funciona direitinho com o plugin WooCommerce Extra Checkout Fields for Brazil, que incrementa o checkout com os campos cpf e cnpj 
 https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-extra-checkout-fields-for-brazil/

Answer (score 1):

Olha pra você fazer ele escolher entre cpf e cnpj você pode colocar uma condição para verificar a quantidade de dígitos se for maior que 12 faça o teste de cnpj se não faça o de cpf.

Comment: A dica é boa, mas você poderia ter deixado um exemplo com código.